# evenly distributed random numbers

Tags: javascript, random

Hey, is there way to choose evenly distributed random numbers? I used this function

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
```

which returns either 1 or 0. However, I dont think it has exact 50% chance to produce either one. Better thoughts? Thank you

Comment: IMO this is OK. `Math.random() * 2` returns a number between 0 and say 1.99; flooring it will give you 0 for values 0-0.99 and 1 for values 1-1.99 so its pretty even. But I am afraid somone's got a better idea.

Comment: Why don't you think it's exactly 50% for either one?  Running this 10000 times and averaging the results gives me 0.5026 which is almost exactly 50% 0's 50% 1's.  (That's in Firefox 4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not believe, check:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total = 0;
var ones = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++, total++) {
  ones += Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
}
alert(ones/total);
</script>
```

This code gives me 0.49972 - very close to 50%.

Answer (score 4):

It should give you even distribution.

```
var a=new Array(0,0); for (i=0; i<100000; i++) a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]++; alert(a);
```

you can try it by copy-pasting to the addressbar:

```
javascript:var a=new Array(0,0); for (i=0; i<100000; i++) a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]++; alert(a);
```

Comment: Ooh, that's a neat trick I hadn't seen before (javascript coding in the address bar). No more writing HTML files with embedded source for me. +1 just for that!

Comment: @paxdiablo Or you could use Firebug's console in Firefox, the included console of Chrome, the included console of Opera. Don't know about other browsers, but they probably have plugins or tools too.

Answer (score 3):

Just try it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var zero=0;
var one=0;

for (var i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
    var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
    if (num) zero++;
    if (!num) one++;
}

document.write("Zero: "+zero+"<br />");
document.write("One: "+one+"<br />");

</script>
```

You're looking for answers in this case which are good to within the square root of a million. i.e. you want the results coming out to be 500,000 +- 1000 if you're getting truly random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It generates 0 or 1 with equal chances.

But why didn't you use:

```
Math.round(Math.random())
```

? Do you want to be able to change to generate 0, 1, 2, ..., N ? If so keep your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It's close enough to 50% to the point where, if you're worried about a discrepancy (if indeed there is one), you wouldn't be using pseudo random numbers in the first place :-)

Running a loop with 10 million iterations gives me a ratio of 5,000,931 to 4,999,069 which is an error of only one in ten thousand (0.00931 percent).

Answer (score 0):

The chance for either result is exactly 50%. What makes you think that it isn't?