# JavaScript: Getting random location on globe

Tags: javascript, random, geolocation

I am trying to create a function that returns a random point on a globe. When I try the following code, it ends up bunching more of the points at the poles and fewer at the equator.

```
function random_location() {
  return {
    lon: Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) - 179,
    lat: Math.floor(Math.random() * 181) - 90
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var location = random_location();
  // do something
}
```

How should I do this?

NOTE: this point might be on a sphere the size of the Earth, but could just as well be any other size. I just need to create randomly evenly distributed latitude and longitude.

Comment: "_randomly evenly distributed_" is not random. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715826/evenly-distributed-random-numbers

Comment: @Teemu Random meaning the computer picks a random number for me and evenly distributed meaning it's not clumped up at the top and bottom of the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html :

```
function random_location() {
  return {
    lon: Math.floor(Math.random()*360) - 180,
    lat: Math.round(Math.acos(2*Math.random() - 1)*180/Math.PI) - 90
  }
}
```